# Non-English speaker as reference in UK Citizenship

Tags: uk-citizenship

I'm filling in the citizenship form for my son, and he needs two references and one has to have worked with him in a professional capacity. We currently live in Bolivia, which is where he is from. I had two options for this, a teacher and a social worker.

Here is the quote from the guide:

> If the child is living abroad and does not know a British citizen who is qualified to act as a referee, a Commonwealth citizen or citizen of the country in which he or she is residing may complete and sign the form, provided they have a similar standing in that country.

His teacher is American, so I think she's out? She does have Bolivian residency though. The social worker I worked with for the adoption is willing to do it, but she's Bolivian and speaks no English. I would need to help her fill in the form, translate it, and have her write her answer, and translate it back into English before having her write it in. That seems very complicated - any idea if it's okay? Any other options?

Comment: She could probably just fill out the form in Spanish. Maybe they even have the forms in that language also.

Comment: Have her fill it out in Spanish, then get a certified translation of the form.